# Passing the file path from javascript to the file upload?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, filepath

I want to let the users type the file path with wildcards and then send it to the file uploader. Is this possible? I couldn't find a way to pass parameters to the file upload. Is there a security reason?

EDIT:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="upload[]" data-url="components/filemanager/controller.php?action=upload&path=<?php echo($_GET['path']); ?>">
```

above is my file upload.

I have an input textbox that users can type the file/folder path.
ex: C:\uploadfolder\

can i pass this path to the file uploader such that it can open that specific folder?

Comment: The content of an `<input type="file" />` is read-only for security reasons, this includes the default directory.

Comment: Is there any alternatives?

Comment: Short answer: No. Longer answer: Not really, you can do file-uploads with Flash but scripts for that are old and you are generally discouraged from using them (known bugs, not compatible with latest Adobe Flash version) and I wouldn't be surprised if Flash has the same restriction as JavaScript even, at least in some browsers. Then there's Java applets... an ancient technology that needs Java installed, enabled in the browser and set to have privileges to read the local hard-drive... I wouldn't even consider it myself honestly.